# Is it possible to post form data using an anchor tag (href)? codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
           <form  id="my-form" method="POST">  
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Employee<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
              <select class="form-control" name="employee" id="employee">
                  <option value="">Select a Employee</option>
                  <?php
                  foreach ($result as $row) { 
                    //var_dump($row);exit();
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?= $row->ID;?>"> <?= $row->FNAME;?> </option>
                 <?php }?>
              </select>

            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
          </div>   

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Start Date<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
              <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type='date' class="form-control" name="sdate">
              </div>
              <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>End Date<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
              <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type='date' class="form-control" name="edate">
              </div>
              <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
               <div style="padding : 20px 50px">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right ;padding-left: 15px ;margin-right: 5px ;margin-top: 5px"   id="view" >view</a>
              </div>

            </div>
              </form>

   <script>
 $(document).on('change','#employee',function(){
var b = $(this).val();
  $("#view").attr('href', '<?= base_url()?>admin/admin_view/'+b);
  });
$("#view").on('click','#view',function(){
$("#my-form").submit();
 });
```

My `href` is generated when I select any name from option. The problem is now that I want to post my data through the anchor tag. I don't know how to do this. I am using codeigniter 3. Hope this code allow you to understand my problem.

If anyone can help me I'll be thankful to him.

Comment: am using jquery and my href is genrated on the basis of value selected now if i use on.click to that anchor its not posting my data

Comment: i have edited the question and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps -

1. When you change the employee, instead of assigning it to the href, assign it to form. Like this -

   $(document).on('change','#employee', function(){

   ```
       var b = $(this).val(); 
       $(form).attr('action',YOUR URL);
   ```

   });
2. In your  tag set href="javascript:void(0)"
3. Click on submit link.

Comment: as am selecting the name which came from database so i wan to perform my all task against the id of each name so that is why i need to pass it using an anchor tag

Comment: you can take a hidden variable and assign it a value same as your id.